# Inconsistent theory $T$ when $T \models \varphi$ for every L-sentence

Tags: logic

I read in a course book that if $T$ is inconsistent, then $T \models \varphi$ for every L-sentence. Can somebody explain me why this holds. I don't ask for a proof or something, just a little explanation

Comment: In classical logic there is a valid "argument form" called [Ex Falso Quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion#Semantic_argument) that means exactly : very sentence follows from a contradiction.

Comment: If $T$ is inconsistent then there are no models of $T$ so "$\varphi$ holds in every model of $T$" is (vacuously) true.

Comment: $p\implies(\lnot p\implies\phi)$ is a tautology...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is inconsistent iff
$$T \vdash \bot$$

i.e. if we can derive a contradiction from $T$.

The key of the argument is that the rule ex falso quodlibet

$$\frac{\bot}{\phi}$$

allows us to derive arbitrary formulas $\phi$ from a contradiction.

Hence if $T$ is inconsistent, by using this rule, we can not only derive $\bot$, but any formula $\phi$ from $T$: $$T \vdash \phi$$

Now we just need to get from $\vdash$ to $\vDash$. This is given by the soundness of our formal system: Any formula that can be derived syntactically ($\vdash$) is also semantically valid ($\vDash$):

$$\Gamma \vdash \phi \Longrightarrow \Gamma \vDash \phi$$

By this, we immedaiately get
$$T \vDash \phi$$
for any formula $\phi$.